# Using scipy and numpy to sort floats

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Can someone help me sort a group of floats into bins no larger than a value of 10? I have two problems in that the program is reading a set of files and creating individual arrays for each value. Second I'm unsure as to what is going on with the numpy binning.

```
for filename in glob.iglob('*.html'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
        results = []

        weight = soup.find('b', text='Shipping Weight:').next_sibling
        title = soup.find("span", id="btAsinTitle")

        results = weight
        import re
        import scipy 
        import numpy as np

        result_str = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", results)
        result = float(result_str[0])
        #print result

        array_weight = [result]

        print array_weight

        x = np.array(array_weight)

        bins = np.array([10.0])

        inds = np.digitize(x, bins)

        print inds
```

Comment: Can you simplify this code a little? We don't need to see all the beautiful soup or `re` stuff to help you with sorting/binning floats.  Start with your array of floats and go from there, otherwise I am a bit lost.

Comment: Small note, bring your import statements _outside_ your loops! Otherwise you incur an overhead at each iteration of that for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the titled question and ignore the others (please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!), a minimal working example for [`numpy.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) is

```
import numpy as np

# Five bins, spaced from 0, 10
bins = np.linspace(0,10,5)

# Some random test data, from 0,10
data = np.random.random(size=20)*10
print data

# Binned data
print np.digitize(data,bins)
```

Which returns

```
[ 9.29893458  0.88322852  4.9592157   7.33677397  0.20901007  5.77875637
  2.49152666  3.55982666  5.33997896  3.76318862  0.35513614  7.12985682
  2.57747437  4.62240375  8.02503782  5.43143368  6.29290487  2.79342587
  3.11806151  5.79996645]
[4 1 2 3 1 3 1 2 3 2 1 3 2 2 4 3 3 2 2 3]
```

It is useful to read over the docs, they tell you the proper input and output!